# What happens if sem_init() is called twice?

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

The man page of sem_init() says "Initializing a semaphore that has already been initialized results in undefined behavior."  Why is that and what exactly will happen on Linux?

This doesn't make sense to me, because when you call sem_init() for the first time, the (uninitialized) sem_t could have exact content as an initialized sem_t -- if the manual is correct, then sem_init() simply doesn't work.

Comment: try it and see for yourself

Comment: I did try and it seemed to work, but the man page made me nervous, as I don't want to be caught off guard in some corner cases..

Comment: @ZhaoWu: In any case you shouldn't do it. If you find yourself needing to, you have a logic bug in your program.

Comment: Absolutely. I was just trying out of curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, where semaphores are implemented without any system resources, `sem_init` just fills in the `sem_t` structure members, and so nothing bad will happen if it's called more than once. However, in general much worse things could happen.

If the `sem_t` is just a dummy object containing a pointer to an allocated object (note: this can't work for process-shared semaphores), you would leak memory by calling `sem_init` multiple times.

Similarly, if `sem_t` just contained a reference (like a file descriptor number) to a kernel-managed resource, you would leak these kernel resources by calling `sem_init` more than once.

Even worse, if the library implementation maintained a linked list of all instantiated semaphores using prev/next pointers inside the `sem_t` object (also not possible for process-shared case), you would corrupt this list by calling `sem_init` on a `sem_t` that's already part of the list.

The standard for POSIX semaphores allows a wide variety of implementation types that might be needed to support implementations on different types of systems (e.g. machines without atomic compare-and-swap instruction, bare-metal with no kernel, ...) so it leaves the behavior undefined so as not to impose requirements that might limit implementation choices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: A related question about the pshared argument in sem_init(). If a semaphore is going to be shared between processes, it has to reside in shared memory. I don't think sem_init() does any shm_open/shmget/mmap, so is this argument used on Linux?

Comment: For the pshared argument to be useful, the `sem_t` whose address you pass to `sem_init` needs to reside in shared memory. You are responsible for providing this shared memory. If could be created by `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and inherited across `fork` (there is no other way to share such memory) or in a sysv or POSIX shared memory segment (`shmget`/`shmat`/etc. or `shm_open`/`mmap`, respectively), or just in a shared mapping of a file.

Answer (score 2):

> > Why is that

Think of it from an API designer's point of view. A semaphore can be seen as an abstract object that is created, used, and eventually disposed of.

Now the task is to map it to C (or any other language). The semaphore implementation will need to acquire resources, possibly resources that are maintained by the operating system. Above live cycle makes a lot of sense.

The API is finalized, and a first implementation is made. Many corner cases or extra requirements come up soon. For example whether `sem_init` can be called multiple times, given that the current implementation makes it trivial to allow it. Another one (maybe) is that it should be possible to select whether semaphores are shared between threads, or processes.

In each case, the API designer will have to weight the trade-offs:

- Is it an extra burden to the implementors of the API?
- Can it be achieved otherwise? (i.e. does it have to be implemented at a library/system level)
- Does it distract from the APIs core functionality?
- Is it considered idiomatic in the language of choice?
- Is it considered a good pattern for APIs in general?
- Is it easy to get wrong / does it impose a security risk?
- ...

In this case, it seems allowing for double initialization would get a *no* by most of these criteria. So the decision is made to not allow it. It probably still works with your particular implementation, compiler, system or even the majority of implementations, compilers, systems.

How to convey that? Well, you call it *undefined behaviour* in the manual and everybody knows not to do it. People with good working intuition for the environment can easily *guess* what the behaviour might be. Only a fool would rely on it, though.

> > the (uninitialized) sem_t could have exact content as an initialized sem_t

That is true. However, let us say the `sem_t` holds a pointer to a piece of heap memory that `sem_init` allocates using `malloc`. It is perfectly possible for a randomly-non-initialized `sem_t` to have the exact same pointer value, but the resource it corresponds to would not exist.